# Chat Application Suggestion .Net

Tags: wcf, sockets, xmpp, duplex

I am going to develop a chat application, I am confused which way I choose. Below are the option, please suggest me which/why is the best way to create a chat application.

1. WCF Duplex chat
2. Socket
3. XMPP

Thanks
Anuj

Answer (score 0):

if you are going for a client server style of chat then ive always found using sockets to be a simple way to do it. If you create the server and add the socket you want it to be listening at.

Create a client that will then connect to the server for this you will enter the ip of the server and the socket. The client then connects to the server and the server will add the client to the client list. When the client sends a message to the server the server will then use a loop the send the message to all the clients in the list.

You will need to make this multi threaded as the clients will always need to be listening for new messages being sent from the server while still allowing the user to send new messages to the server. Its not very complicated at all a quick google and you will find all the code you could ever need for it